# Windows 7 PC with MacDrive cannot read from Mac booted in target mode

Tags: windows, mac

My MacBook Pro has somehow borked its install of Mac OS X, so I'm planning to restore from a Time Machine backup.  However, that backup is a couple of days old, so I was *hoping* to copy all the files off so I can fill in the ones that have been created since then.

I installed MacDrive on my PC, connected the two with a FireWire cable, and booted the Mac into target mode.  So far so good - the bouncy FireWire logo shows up on the Mac's screen.  However, the device shows up in Windows only as "AAPL UNKNOWN MODEL IEEE 1394 SPB2 Device" - I don't get the hard drive listed in Windows Explorer.  I've previously connected a Mac drive using an external enclosure and that one showed up fine, so I know (?) it's not a problem with my install of MacDrive.

Has anyone run into this before?  What could the problem be, and is there any way to get my files off other than opening up the Mac and dropping its hard drive into an enclosure?

Comment: Also, if anyone with more than 300 reputation can edit this and add the 'macdrive' tag I'd appreciate it... thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure it's that easy to abuse Target Disk Mode to mount Mac drives. Can you get hold of an external enclosure?

Comment: Prior to this problem was Windows able to read the drive.  I have never known Windows to recongize a hdd that had been formated by Apple OS X.

Comment: @Ramhound Why did you remove the tag again? This is a specific application for Windows, I don't see why there couldn't be a tag for it. If it isn't used that much, the system will remove it anyway. Plus, Windows *can* read OS X drives using exactly that particular application.

Comment: @slhck: Thanks for editing/commenting... I eventually gave up and opened up the MBP again, removed the drive / mounted it in an enclosure.  However, I'm going to leave the question open, because from what little I can find on the Internet MacDrive should work for target mode drives just as well as it works for enclosures (and it would be nice not to have to do this again...).